# Please merge or change this tag due to misspelling?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, specific-tag, retagging

The tag 'menorah-chanukia' should be changed or merged *quickly* into a 'menorah-chanuka' tag. Judaism SE seems to be using Chanuka as a standard for spelling the Festival of Lights holiday, which is fine with me. Thus my other reasoning for asking about changing to **menorah-chanuka**.

Also, a misspelling like this, **chanukia** is particularly visible now that the time is almost upon us. It would be nice to have this done in the next few days. I would be happy to assist if I were to have sufficient points. Thank you for your attention to this matter. (I tried editing the tag wiki, but that isn't the way to go about it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Chanukia* is (a transliteration of) the modern Hebrew word for the lamp lit on *Chanuka*. We do have a separate [chanuka](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chanuka) tag for the holiday.

Comment: Thank you! I see now that there are tag synonyms for all varieties of Chanuka, Hannuka, Hanukah etc. And more to the point, thank you for clarifying the transliteration of Chanukia as modern Hebrew for light lit on Chanuka, thus validating the menorah-chanukia tag (and making my request unncessary, possibly erroneous).